# Going from Assembly to C code

Tags: c, assembly, att

This is in AT&T syntax

```
.global bar
.type bar, @function

bar:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
pushl %ebx
subl $20, %esp
movl 8($ebp), %ebx
movl $1, %eax
cmpl $1, %ebx
jle .L3
leal -1(%ebx), %eax  //subtracts 1 from ebx and stores into eax
movl %eax, (%esp)    //putting on stack frame
call bar             //recursive call
addl %ebx, %eax      // adds %ebx and %eax


.L3                  //returns %eax
addl $20, %esp
popl %ebx
popl %ebp
ret                  //end of bar
```

So what I think happens here is basically it checks if %ebx is <= 1 and if it is, it returns one. otherwise, it calls bar with x--;

So my C code is:

```
int bar (int x)
{
if (x<= 1)
return 1;
else
return x + bar(x-1);
}
```

The recursive call is really tricking me up here. I realize it calls bar with the new %eax register (which basically becomes x-1). So does it just return the sum of the numbers?

Comment: I don't see where you get `x+(x-1)` for the recursive call argument. There's an `add` *after* the call which you seem to be mixing up with what happens *before* the call. `leal -1(%ebx),%eax` is a *load effective address* instruction. It's documented in the x86 manual (lots of it online). It's used to store an address with an offset, but here as is sometimes the case it's used to save one instruction by doing a move and constant add in one go. I don't see where *adding of `eax` onto the stack* occurs. You must mean *moving* it to the stack, which is necessary to pass it as an arg to `bar`.

Comment: @lurker I realized I messed up the recursive call of it, I am working on retracing it. the leal command is subtracting 1 from ebx and storing it into eax though correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @lurker I have re-looked at it and attempted the solution again. I think it is effectively just summing the values from x to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd annotate it this way:

```
bar:                     // bar() {
    pushl %ebp           //   function prologue
    movl %esp, %ebp      //
    pushl %ebx           //
    subl $20, %esp       //
    movl 8($ebp), %ebx   //   %ebx = x
    movl $1, %eax        //   %eax = 1
    cmpl $1, %ebx        //   if (x > 1)
    jle .L3              //   {
    leal -1(%ebx), %eax  //     %eax = x - 1
    movl %eax, (%esp)    //     put (x - 1) on stack
    call bar             //     %eax = bar(x - 1)
    addl %ebx, %eax      //     %eax += x
.L3                      //   }
    addl $20, %esp       //   function epilogue
    popl %ebx            //
    popl %ebp            //
    ret                  //   return %eax
                         // }
```

So the C looks quite equivalent to what you posted:

```
int bar (int x)
{
  if (x > 1)
    return bar(x - 1) + x;

  return 1;
}
```

---

For historical interest: I compiled your original (incorrect) C code using `clang -m32 -S` and after "optimizing" slightly by hand to eliminate a store/load pair, I got something resembling your assembly code, but it was pretty clear you had it wrong at that moment.  You fixed it since then.

Comment: I'd simplify the comments on the `push %ebp / mov %esp, %ebp` to `// stack frame boilerplate`.  "Stack as called" isn't even totally accurate, since it's done after a push.  Also, "unwind" implies (to me anyway) following the linked list of stack frames back up the call chain to some parent function's stack frame.  I'd have said "restore stack pointer to where we saved our registers", or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Fair enough--I replaced those comments with "prologue" and "epilogue" now which I think is pretty standard.

Comment: Yup, I like it.  It's not part of the function logic, just part of implementing it for that ABI (with some call-preserved registers and the usual stack-frame convention).  Not what you need to focus on when tracing the actual logic to see what a function does.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bar(int x)
{
if (x<= 1)
return 1;
else
return x+bar(x-1);
}
```

sums x to 1 in ascending order